# Extending DS2408 IOs with MAX7219 or 74HC595

Tags: arduino, 1-wire, 74hc595

I have an idea of building a model traffic lights node with Arduino. One node should serve the whole intersection with all the lights from all directions.

I want to use a 1-wire [DS2408](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/digital/memory-products/DS2408.html) to identify the node by its factory set unique id and have its 8 IOs for different lights.

One node should have more lights (for difficult intersections more than 30-40). I want to use some LED driver like MAX7219 or shift register like 74HC595 to extend these 8 IOs to 64.

Can something like this be done? Can I use DS2408 (1-Wire 8-Channel Addressable Switch) and extend its IOs? Or what would you suggest?

I want to use this 1-wire protocol for better scalability and easy node addressing, let's say I want to build a model city with 100 intersections.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Maxim Application Note 4505 One-Wire Network Controls Remote SPI Peripherals](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4505):

> To produce the 3-wire SPI™ interface required by a MAX7221 display controller (active-low CS, DIN, and CLK), this 1-Wire® network serially addresses three 1-Wire switches (DS2413). The first switch creates Chip Select directly (active-low CS), the second creates the serial-data line directly (DIN), and the third switch—with the help of three exclusive-OR gates—creates the serial clock (CLK).

By directly controlling the clock instead of using the 3 XOR ICs, you can cut down on parts at the expense of speed. A single DS2408 could control up to 6 MAX7219 that way (Clk, DIN, and 6 Chip Selects). It **really** depends on the speed/led response time you need.

PWM or Synchronized lights through the MAX7219s this way of a high number of lights would probably not work well just due to the number of bytes that need to be sent.

A better solution is i2c port expanders with i2c bus switches. OR microcontrollers acting as i2c port expanders. Cheaper, and more customizable in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So maybe it would be easier to build just some mesh network with independent controllers for each node, I can use some unique ID (DS18B20 as temperature sensor and unique ID in one shot) and expand with MAX7219 to drive all lights.